# Not able to select 'Pin To Start'

Tags: pin-to-start

I want to put an application to the start menu (Pin to start), but it is greyed out and it's not already in the start menu.

How can I fix this without having to uninstall and reinstall the application again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to get a clear idea of your question so please correct me by explaining a bit further if I mentioned something irrelevant to what you wanted. If you are actually using a Windows Phone, I can interpret that you are in the All Apps menu and are not able to get Pin to Start menu option. You may be using Windows Phone 8.1 or Windows 10 Mobile in this case.

From the provided assumption, it seems like your phone is experiencing a glitch and a simple restart would fix it. If it didn't then try soft reset that would **not** change or delete your data at all. It's generally safe and you can perform a soft reset by holding Volume Up key + Power key at the same time for about 12-15 seconds. A soft reset will restart your phone and hence, should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what problem I have ... I'm currently running a cleaner which probably takes an entire day so tomorrow I can try a reset (didn't know about the soft reset).

Comment: Hey @MichelKeijzers, a soft reset is a just a restart. It won't take more than a minute.

Comment: I know but I don't want to stop that clean program ... it takes like many hours more and have to restart iti again if I close the app.

Comment: What cleaner is that?